# Is "from matplotlib import pyplot as plt" == "import matplotlib.pyplot as plt"?

Tags: python, matplotlib, python-import

```
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt

import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
```

Are the above statements equivalent? Which is more readable/better form?

Answer (score 55, accepted):

Even though they are equivalent, I think there is a pretty good argument that the second form `import matplotlib.pyplot as plt` is objectively more readable:

1. It is generally customary to use `import matplotlib.pyplot as plt` and suggested in the matplotlib documentation (see http://matplotlib.org/users/pyplot_tutorial.html etc...) so this will be more familiar to most readers.
2. `import matplotlib.pyplot as plt` is shorter but no less clear.
3. `import matplotlib.pyplot as plt` gives an unfamiliar reader a hint that [pyplot](https://github.com/matplotlib/matplotlib/blob/master/lib/matplotlib/pyplot.py) is a module, rather than a function which could be incorrectly assumed from the first form.

Comment: Hey, I'm trying to get a hang of the terminology. Is "pyplot" alone the module and "matplotlib" also a module? Or is "matplotlib.pyplot" the module? Thanks!

Comment: [matplotlib](https://github.com/matplotlib/matplotlib/blob/master/lib/matplotlib/__init__.py) is a package, essentially a collection of related modules. At its simplest, a package can be just a directory containing the module files with an empty `__init__.py` file that tells python that the directory is to be treated as a package. A module `B` within package `A` (i.e. in the file structure `A/B.py` is imported as `import A.B`

Comment: @EricAppelt Is the syntax `A.B` the same with attributes of an object?

Answer (score 14):

They both work the same so it is up to you which you prefer, personally I don't like typing so I would prefer the second.

```
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt

import matplotlib.pyplot as plt1

print(dir(plt) == dir(plt1))
True
```

Answer (score 4):

Just noticed one case that makes the two statements work differently to me

```
import matplotlib
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
matplotlib.use('Qt5Agg')

plt.plot(list(range(10)))
```

The above code works well.
But if I write the second line in the other way,

```
import matplotlib
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt
matplotlib.use('Qt5Agg')

plt.plot(list(range(10)))
```

This above doensn't work and the process stops at "matplotlib.use('Qt5Agg')".
Process finished with exit code -1073741571 (0xC00000FD)

This happens in IDE like Spyder console or Pycharm console. I feel it's related to the backend used though I didn't have a clear clue.

Comment: I see a similar problem in PyCharm 2021.3 and PyCharm 2022: when doing `import matplotlib.pyplot as plt` it works, but if I do `from matplotlib import pyplot as plt` I get a gui window that is blank and title `Not Responding`. My Colleagues also run PyCharm, but do not have this problem.

Answer (score 3):

Yes, both are the same.

It depends on you what you prefer to import.

Personally, I like to write:

```py
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt
```

because it looks clearer and cleaner to me.